# Редактируемое значение в Yii

Tags: php, yii

Мне нужно вывести редактируемое поле (по клику появляется поле ввода).

**Особенности**:

1. Желательно **не** всплывающее окно;
2. В режиме редактирования необходимо добавить дополнительную кнопку (например кнопка Max)

**Наработки**:

Разбираюсь с виджетом `editable.EditableField`. Но в нем не получается настроить параметр `mode: inline`. Так-же во временном тупике как добавить свою кнопку.

***Как и с помощью чего лучше сделать редактируемое значение?***

Comment: я думаю, тут лучше сделать всё стандартными средствами javascript. ещё вот натыкался на вот эту статью http://habrahabr.ru/post/143800/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поддержу [@Heleg](/users/8836/heleg). Сделайте обычным javascript. Логика такая: На поле которое должно быть редактируемое вешаете обработчик `click`. При клике - вставляете input поверх поля, которое редактируете. Кстати, input можно создать при рендере страницы и абсолютным позиционированием ставить его в нужное место. Далее... после завершения редактирования(потеря фокуса, энтер или кнопка), отправляете ajax запрос на сервер с id записи и новым значением. Обновляете БД, если приходит положительный результат - обновляете через js значение в html, если нет -предупреждение пользователю.

Comment: собственно я так и сделал, получилось прилично ) спасибо )

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант сделать модальное окно.
Ну с js скорее всего проще. Да и ответ дан.
Если с модальным окном

```
$id = $rows[$i]['id_elem'];
$link = Yii::app()->createUrl('analiz/analizCreate/elemupd');    
$val = 'Chtml::link(num($data->id,' . $id . '), 
"", array("onclick"=>"on2(\'' . $link . '?elem_id=' . $id . '&value=$data->id\')"))';   
 $myarray[] = array(
        'header' =>  $rows[$i]['name'], //имя столбца 
        'type' => 'raw',
        'value' => $val,
        'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width: 15px; text-align:center;'),
        'headerHtmlOptions' => array('style' => 'text-align:center'),
        'footer' => sum($id),
        );
```

то есть сформировали массив колнок, где значение - ссылка
при клике обращаемся к js функции

```
<script>
    function on2(id) {
        //alert(id);
        $("#myModalHeader").html('');
        $("#myModalBody").load(id);
        $("#myModal").modal();
    }
</script>
```

где модальное окно

```
<!-- модальное окно -->
    <?php
    $this->beginWidget(
            'bootstrap.widgets.TbModal', array('id' => 'myModal')
    );
    ?>

<div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
    <h4 id="myModalHeader">Modal header</h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-body" id="myModalBody">
    <p>One fine body...</p>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
<?php
$this->widget(
        'bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
    'label' => 'Close',
    'url' => '#',
    'htmlOptions' => array('data-dismiss' => 'modal'),
        )
);
?>
</div>
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
<!-- модальное окно -->
```

в контроллере отображаем вью, при получении данных записываем

```
public function actionElemupd()
{
    if ($_POST['val'])
    {
        $val = $_POST['val'][0];

        $connection = Yii::app()->db;
        $sql = "                
             ";
        $dataReader = $connection->createCommand($sql)->execute();
        $this->redirect(array('admin'));
    }

    $this->renderPartial('elem_upd');
}
```

вью можем прописать любую

```
<?php
$form = $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
    'id' => 'analiz-create-form',
    // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
    // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
    // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
    // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
    'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
        // 'htmlOptions'=>array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'),
        ));
?>
<?php
  echo CHtml::label('elem', 'elem');
  echo CHtml::textField('val[]', 'name');
  ?>
<?php
$this->widget(
        'bootstrap.widgets.TbButton',
        array(
            'label' => 'Сохранить',
            'buttonType' => 'submit',
        )
);

?>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?